# List.Find<T>() returning null even though predicate matches

Tags: c#, .net

I'll just attach a picture for reference on this one. I am stumped. In the debugger, the values definitely equal each other, but `Find<T>` is still returning null and `Exists<T>` is still returning false. For reference: `UserRepository` implements `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is `DomainUser`.

[image: Debug screencap]

Comment: Try converting to a byte array and checking the byte-codes. I'm guessing one of them has an appended '0' byte.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `CommandArgument` is `object`, so it's performing a reference identity check. (I'm surprised this isn't giving you a compile-time warning.)

You could either cast `CommandArgument` to `string`, or use `Equals`:

```
u => u.Username == (string) args.CommandArgument
```

or

```
u => Equals(u.Username, args.CommandArgument)
```

(Using the static `Equals` method this way means it'll work even for users with a `null` username, unlike `u.Username.Equals(args.CommandArgument)`.)

I wouldn't convert the sequence to a list though - I'd just use LINQ instead:

```
DomainUser toRemove =
    repo.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == (string) args.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I can use `FirstOrDefault` without calling `ToList`. I guess I had only looked at the type of `CommandArgument` on the `Control` (it is `String`) and not the `RepeaterCommandEventArgs`.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried :

```
u.Username.Equals(args.CommandArgument)
```